# A (slightly complex) SQL Query?

Tags: sql, ms-access, select, sum, union

I have this complex (to me) requirement and would appreciate a SQL query for it. Here's the deal:

- There's this table named "Expenses" in an Access file.
- The table contains fields as "Category," "Amount," "Payer," and "IsShare."
- Category can be Gas, Groceries, Home, etc...
- Amount is the dollar amount for the expense.
- Payer can either be me or my brother ("Me" or "Bro").
- IsShare can either be true or false. Basically if IsShare is true, then the expense is divided in two. Otherwise, the payer pays for it all.

I need a SQL query to calculate all my expenses for a particular Category. It should be calculated as such:

- 100% of all non-shared items that I've paid (Payer = 'Me' AND IsShare = false),
- 50% of all shared items that I've paid (Payer = 'Me' AND IsShare = true), and
- 50% of all shared items that my brother's paid (Payer = 'Bro' AND IsShare = true).

The query should return the sum of all these three items.

So far I have a preliminary query, but it returns incorrect results. Could someone correct it for me?

Thank you very much.

```
return @"SELECT Sum(Amount) AS TotalAmount " +
        "FROM Expenses " +
        "WHERE Category = 'Groceries' " +
        "AND Payer = 'Me' " +
        "AND Share = false " +
        "GROUP BY Category " +
        "UNION " +
        "SELECT 0.5 * Sum(Amount) AS TotalAmount " +
        "FROM Expenses " +
        "WHERE Category = 'Groceries' " +
        "AND Payer = 'Me' " +
        "AND Share = true " +
        "GROUP BY Category " +
        "UNION " +
        "SELECT 0.5 * Sum(Amount) AS TotalAmount " +
        "FROM Expenses " +
        "WHERE Category = 'Groceries' " +
        "AND Payer = 'Bro' " +
        "AND Share = true ";
        "GROUP BY Category";
```

Comment: What database engine is this for, SQL Server?

Comment: I would just want to confirm the field name. First you say it's isShare, but in your code you use plain Share

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Santa! I always like to remind new users that upvoting and accepting (checkmarks) questions is the primary means of showing appreciation. If you have any questions, the [FAQ] is a great resource, especially the [ASK]

Comment: Of course he can't upvote until he has some reputation :)

Comment: True, I usually put that in for when they can :) It is my standard welcome.

Comment: Thank you for the nice welcome, guys. I am familiar with StackOverflow, since 95% of my Google research usually leads me here to you guys' gracious and selfless help.

Comment: @Brettski: It's MS Access. I recall having a hard time installing SQL Server, so I had to be saddled with MS Access...

Comment: @ ta.speot.is: I'll do some research on the UNION ALL. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Yes, you're right, it should be IsShare. Sorry for the typo.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not seeing how UNION ALL would do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the UNION is needed for what you are trying to do.  This will pass over the data once and put the values in individual columns.  You may need to cast or convert the 0.5 to a specific type, I didn't have a chance to run this.

```
SELECT 
     Category,
     SUM(CASE WHEN Payer='me' AND NOT IsShare THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) as IPaid,
     SUM(CASE WHEN Payer='me' AND IsShare THEN Amount * 0.5 ELSE 0 END) as SharedPay,
     SUM(CASE WHEN Payer='bro' AND IsShare THEN Amount * 0.5 ELSE 0 END) as BrotherPay
FROM Eexpenses
WHERE Category = 'Groceries'
GROUP BY Category
```

For MS ACCESS:

```
SELECT 
     Category,
     SUM(IIF(Payer='me' AND NOT IsShare, Amount,0)) as IPaid,
     SUM(IIF(Payer='me' AND IsShare, Amount * 0.5, 0)) as SharedPay,
     SUM(IIF(Payer='bro' AND IsShare, Amount * 0.5, 0)) as BrotherPay
FROM Eexpenses
WHERE Category = 'Groceries'
GROUP BY Category
```

Add the three columns together:

```
SELECT Category, IPaid, SharedPay, BrotherPay, IPay + SharedPay + BotherPay as Total 
FROM (
    SELECT 
         Category,
         SUM(IIF(Payer='me' AND NOT IsShare, Amount,0)) as IPaid,
         SUM(IIF(Payer='me' AND IsShare, Amount * 0.5, 0)) as SharedPay,
         SUM(IIF(Payer='bro' AND IsShare, Amount * 0.5, 0)) as BrotherPay
    FROM Eexpenses
    WHERE Category = 'Groceries'
    GROUP BY Category
) as T1
```

Comment: The question is tagged with `access`. Good luck with that `CASE WHEN`.

Comment: Thanks @ta.speot.is didn't see that tag for some reason.  Access version added.

Comment: Thank you, Brettski. Looks really good. I wrote a method that grabs reader[1], reader[2], and reader[3], adds them up, and returns their sum. But is there a way for a single query to do that? [EDIT: Can it be done with UNION ALL, as ta.speot.is proposed?]

Comment: You can just add the three columns (fields) in an outer query, @Santa.

Comment: What @Santa suggested would surely work.  Or you can repeat all three iif statements in one column, though that seems pretty messy and duplicates code.